# Type conversion in R based on type of another variable?

Tags: r

I have code that look like this:

```
if(inherits(index(x),"POSIXct"))index_d=as.POSIXct(rownames(d))
else if(inherits(index(x),"Date"))index_d=as.Date(rownames(d))
else stop(paste0("x uses a date index (",attr(x,".indexCLASS"),") we are not expecting..."))
```

(`x` is an XTS object, but I was hoping for a generic solution. However something that just works with XTS objects, would be good enough for this particular code!)

I.e. what I am looking for is some magical command like:

```
index_d = as.same.type.as(index(x),rownames(d))
```

---

BTW, I also have this quite similar code:

```
if(inherits(index(x),"POSIXct"))rownames(d)=as.character(dates,format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
else rownames(d)=dates    #Rely on implicit conversion from Date to character
```

I suspect this is a different kettle of fish, and also "tough"; just thought I'd mention it in case R does have some magical way to do this. (I have to use the explicit `format` for POSIXct because the implicit conversion will take "2012-06-21 00:00:00" and write it out as "2012-06-21" not "2012-06-21 00:00:00")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can accomplish what you are talking about with the builtin `as()` function:

```
as.same.type.as <- function(instance_of_target_class, object_to_convert) {
    return(as(object_to_convert, 
    class(instance_of_target_class)))
    }
```

Comment: Thanks - that was exactly the type of function I was hoping I'd find. But it appears `as(x,'Date')` doesn't do `as.Date('x')`, but instead says _no method or default for coercing “character” to “Date”_
Someone else found same problem here, but with no solution given:
https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2010-February/229371.html
I guess it might be impossible?

Comment: P.S. `as(x,'Date',strict=F)` also fails.

Comment: right so there are some builtin coerce methods you can check with the command `showMethods(coerce)` or specifically `canCoerce(x, cl)`. In your case the coercion you want is not built in, so you will need to make a custom date class that inherits from the current one and additionally supplies a custom coercion method. the `as` function just calls whatever `coerce` method is defined in the class